# How to add a value of right zeros in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

What I want is to add a certain number of zeros, for example, 3, at the end of the tensor. This is an example (with an invented tf funcion):

```py
tn = tf.constant([1, 2])
# out: <tf.Tensor: shape(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2])>

tn = tf.add_zeros(tn, 3, 'right')
# out: <tf.Tensor: shape(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 0, 0, 0])>
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: will `tn` always have the same shape before adding zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `tf.concat`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tn = tf.constant([1, 2])
# out: <tf.Tensor: shape(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2])>

tn = tf.concat([tn, tf.zeros((3), dtype=tf.int32)], axis=0)
print(tn)
```

```
tf.Tensor([1 2 0 0 0], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
```

Or with `tf.pad`

```py
t = tf.constant([1, 2])
paddings = tf.constant([[0, 3]])
tf.pad(t, paddings, "CONSTANT")
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: thank you! and one off the question, so I understant if you don't answer, how to cut ang going from tf.Tensor(1, 2, 3, 4) to tf.Tensor(1, 2)?

Comment: I solved it by using its own index. Sorry was a dumb question